# Date according to sheetname script | "too many scripts running simultaneously" Errors

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Purpose:
Date each sheet in A1
Sheetnames are 1-31
Sheet '1'A1 Gets a manually entered date for the first of the month:
ie 1/3/2024
Sheet '2'A1 is: ='1'!A1+SHEETNAME(0)-1

[Demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D7_Se3XywQ8ysfRBhNt8DRxfsjeULM08T85-o298goI/edit?usp=sharing)

[image: error message]

These errors constantly happen everytime a sheet is loaded or called upon to pull data from.

My question is:

1. is there a better solution than this?
2. if no to 1, how to prevent these errors?

Note: I have 31 sheets per spreadsheet, 12 spreadsheets per year,
and over 2 years worth. Thats over 800 edits that I dont want to do
manually. So the solution cannot be to have a custom number on each
sheet. It must be scripted according to SHEETNAME TIA

Im geeting "too many scripts running simultaneously" errors throughout my spreadsheet witht the current code:

```js
/**
 * Gets the Sheet Name of a selected Sheet.
 *
 * @param {number} option 0 - Current Sheet, 1 All Sheets, 2 Spreadsheet filename
 * @return The input multiplied by 2.
 * @customfunction
 */
function SHEETNAME(option) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var thisSheet = sheet.getName();
  //Current option Sheet Name
  if (option === 0) {
    return thisSheet;
    //All Sheet Names in Spreadsheet
  } else if (option === 1) {
    var sheetList = [];
    ss.getSheets().forEach(function (val) {
      sheetList.push(val.getName());
    });
    return sheetList;
    //The Spreadsheet File Name
  } else if (option === 2) {
    return ss.getName();
    //Error
  } else {
    return "#N/A";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be more efficient to do it via a regular script rather than multiple invocations of a custom function:

```js
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
function setUpDates() {
  const SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const baseDate = SS.getSheetByName("1").getRange("A1").getValue();
  const sheets = SS.getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    // Convert sheet names into numbers, all non-numbers will be NaN
    const nameNum = sheet.getName() * 1;
    // Skip if it is a wrong sheet or the first one with the base date
    if (!nameNum || nameNum === 1) return;
    sheet.getRange("A1").setValue(
      // Add number of milliseconds in one day
      new Date(baseDate.getTime() + 86400000 * (nameNum - 1))
    );
  })
}

// Optional: add to the main menu
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Setup")
    .addItem("Set up dates", "setUpDates")
    .addToUi();
}
```

Notes:

1. You need to run it only once during setup of the spreadsheet.  I assume that once a spreadsheet is created, the dates do not change.
2. The script makes assumptions:

   - The sheet with the first date is named "1".
   - Only the sheets that have numeric names are the sheets which need to be updated.
   - The cell that needs to be updated is `A1`.
3. On the first run this script will require permission to update the document it is installed in.

Comment: You are a legend! Your assumptions are 100% correct and that works perfectly.

Now I just need to apply this to about 30 existing spreadsheets.

Thank you very much sir